# Apache POI : Difference between row.getLastCellNum and row.getNoOfPhysicalCell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

What is the difference between `row.getLastCellNum()` and `row.getNoOfPhysicalCell()` in POI HSSFRow ? Or are they same ?

Comment: Both of them return me the same answer

Comment: row.getNoOfPhysicalCell() will take non-empty cell count but row.getLastCellNum() will take last number of cell.values of them may vary if you have empty or null cells in your excel sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getLastCellNum()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getLastCellNum%28%29)

> Gets the index of the last cell contained in this row PLUS ONE

[getPhysicalNumberOfCells()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getPhysicalNumberOfCells)

> gets the number of defined cells (NOT number of cells in the actual row!). That is to say if only columns 0,4,5 have values then there would be 3.

Comment: Both of them return me 68 . Even if i deleted few columns in the sheet. Why so ? I am deleting not only contents but objects and formulas also.

Answer (score 0):

getLastRowNum() retrieves the index of the last row in a spreadsheet. These indexes are 0 based, and if you have no missing rows, 100th row that is the last row will have index 99. getPhysicalNumberOfRows() returns the number of rows actually used in the spreadsheet. Unused rows are just missing from the spreadsheet. So you could have a situation where you only have one row at row 100th. In that case getPhysicalNumberOfRows() would return 1, but getLastRowNum() would return 99.

Comment: note -  rows that had content before and were set to empty later might still be counted as rows.