# POI: wrong number of cell per row form method getPhysicalNumberOfCells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using POI java library to read an Excel.

My Exel have a simple structure composed by 8 columns.

The problem is that reading column length by method getPhysicalNumberOfCells I get different number for each row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get number of columns of a particular row in given excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489817/get-number-of-columns-of-a-particular-row-in-given-excel)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that getPhysicalNumberOfCells  has a different meaning of what I was thinking.

getPhysicalNumberOfCells  returns the number of cell in a row that have a content.

In fact POI stores for each row only the data added into exel, for example if you have data in columns 0,3,5, getPhysicalNumberOfCells   will return always 3, beacause 3 is the number of "filled" cells.

To achive the purpose of get the logical numeber of cell in a row we use:

```
getLastCellNum()
```

According whit documentation, this method gets the index of the last cell. This value is increased BY ONE, so in the example above, whit maximum index of 5 will be 6..
I think this has been done to simplify iteration over rowcell.

Moreover, there is a method

```
getLastCellNum
```

that show first cell index.

An example inspired from official documentation:

```
  short minColIdx = row.getFirstCellNum();
  short maxColIdx = row.getLastCellNum();
  for(short colIdx=minColIdx ; colIx<maxColIdx ; colIdx++) {
     Cell cell = row.getCell(colIx);
    //get value of cell
```

}

Comment: Wow, according to what I see, you put yourself your answer the exact same moment you posted your question.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: This can be done only if you think what you know, other don't know... but we all know the difference between the two you are saying... once you have done the same... please accept the answer so that it cannot be taken as unresolved problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18489900/624003,  

http://stackoverflow.com/q/18201381/624003

Comment: There will be no complete iteration if sheet contain empty cell though value of last cell is fine.